# CSS Stripes, repeating-linear-gradient bug

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I have a striped divider in CSS, with repeating linear gradient, but it is doing some strange thing, here is an image :

[image: Bug]

As you can see, the thickness of some of the stripes are not the same, I would like to have the striped divider like this, but all with the same "font-weight", I tried to fix the code adding or reducing pixels, but not working

Here is the code :

```css
.striped_divider {
height: 20px;
    background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(135deg,               transparent 2px, transparent 7px,#cccccc 8px,#cccccc 8px);
    background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent        2px, transparent 7px,#cccccc 8px,#cccccc 8px);
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 2px,      transparent 7px,#cccccc 8px,#cccccc 8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="striped_divider"></div>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with `font-weight`?

Comment: All the lines are equal, there is not a problem with font-weight. What you see (And we see) is a ilussion created by the suceccion of lines. To check if they are weight equal, just see closely pressing ctrl + to zoom the web.

Comment: both output as show and code are some

Comment: @Roy It does not seem to be an optical illusion, atleast my browser does draw some the lines "thicker"

Comment: @Roy It's nothing to do with an optical illusion. It's a browser rendering issue. Chrome often has this making 1px lines blurry depending on how they are positioned.

Comment: Yes, my browser too. But you tried to zoomx5 on lines? if you zoom, all lines are equal, that's mean that the browser can't draw at details when is in zoom normal.

Comment: So, there is no way to do little lines like I want ?

Comment: Make a repeated image. (Slow resources)

Comment: @Roy skew transformation on a straight gradient seems to give better results

Comment: Yeah, I did it with an image so, standard way. But If you have any idea on how to render thick line in CSS it would be good, I mean to lower resource usage, I always prefer to use CSS instead of images

Answer (score 2):

You can do nothing, this is how gradient are rendred when we deal with small close values (especially in Google Chrome, in Fiferfox it should be better).

Increase the values and you will see that the effect will slowly disappear:

```css
.striped_divider0 {
  height: 20px;
  margin:5px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 2px, transparent 7px, #cccccc 8px, #cccccc 8px);
}

.striped_divider {
  height: 20px;
  margin:5px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 2px, transparent 7px, #cccccc 7px, #cccccc 8px);
}

.striped_divider1 {
  height: 20px;
  margin:5px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 2px, transparent 7px, #cccccc 7px, #cccccc 10px);
}
.striped_divider2 {
  height: 20px;
  margin:5px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 2px, transparent 7px, #cccccc 7px, #cccccc 15px);
}
```

```html
<div class="striped_divider0"></div>
<div class="striped_divider"></div>
<div class="striped_divider1"></div>
<div class="striped_divider2"></div>
```

You can try skew transformation, it should give better result:

```css
.striped_divider {
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, transparent 2px, transparent 9px, #cccccc 10px, #cccccc 10px);
  transform: skew(-45deg);
}

.striped_divider1 {
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 2px, transparent 7px, #cccccc 8px, #cccccc 8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="striped_divider"></div>
<div class="striped_divider1"></div>
```

Comment: Nice trick using skew !!!. Maybe you should increase the spacing to make it identical to the un-skewed one.

Comment: @vals done ;) and for the accuracy the distance should be  `sqrt(2) *` the initial distance

Answer (score 2):

It indeed seems like a rendering issue, at least in Chrome.
To get around this, you can use `linear-gradient` & `background-size` instead:

```css
.striped_divider {
    height: 20px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-45deg,
    #cccccc 6.25%,
    #ffffff 6.25%,
    #ffffff 50%,
    #cccccc 50%,
    #cccccc 56.25%,
    #ffffff 56.25%,
    #ffffff 100%
  );
  background-size: 8px 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="striped_divider"></div>
```

I made this using https://stripesgenerator.com

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the example below (I've added a css zoom) the lines are indeed the same width. As @Roy already said, it's just an optical illusion.

Edit: I noticed I didn't provide you with a possible solution. As already noted by @Roy, a possible solution would be to repeat an image. The image doesn't have to be particularly high quality, so I don't think it will influence your performance.

```css
.striped_divider {
height: 20px;
    background: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(135deg,               transparent 2px, transparent 7px,#cccccc 8px,#cccccc 8px);
    background: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(135deg, transparent        2px, transparent 7px,#cccccc 8px,#cccccc 8px);
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, transparent 2px,      transparent 7px,#cccccc 8px,#cccccc 8px);
transform: scale(2.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="striped_divider"></div>
```

Comment: Is more like "browser low quality render" than "optical illusion" but you're right. And the solution will be create a repeated image to make it with more quality